# magento 1.9 custom order grid condition

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, order-grid

Am using **Magento 1.9.3**. Here am creating a custom `order gird` in `admin->sales->order` table, those columns following

1. Coupon Code
2. Sliver Exchange Declaration

In `Coupon Code` is used to showing `coupon_code` name for the order.

And `Sliver Exchange Declaration` is showing some link

for the more info for following image 
[image]

My query i would like to show `Silver Exchange Declaration` when `coupon code = SE50` otherwise don't show the `Sliver Exchange Declaration`

My codes
`app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
        'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('silver_exchange' => 'coupon_code'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

In `protected function _prepareColumns()`

```
$this->addColumn('coupon_code', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Coupon Code'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     => '50px',
          'index'     => 'silver_exchange',
          'filter'    => false,
          'sortable'  => false,
        )); //code for coupon_code



$this->addColumn('silver_exchange', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sliver Exchange Declaration'),
                'index' => 'silver_exchange',
                //'filter_index' => 'payment.method',
                //'type'  => 'options',
                //'options' => $silver_exchange,
                'width' => '170px',
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'type'      => 'action',
                'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Silver Exchange Declaration'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/declaration'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                )); //code for Silver Exchange Declaration
```

> query is if coupon code is `SE50` showing `Silver Exchange Declaration` link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a renderer for this as follow.

app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Silverexchange.php

```
<?php
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Silverexchange extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {    
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($value);
        $coupon_code = $order->getCouponCode();

        if($coupon_code == 'SE50') {
            $text = '<a href="'.Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/declaration', array("order_id" => $row->getId())).'">Silver Exchange Declaration</a>';
        } else {
            $text = '';
        }

        return $text; 
    }
}
?>
```

And in app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php change following code under function protected function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('silver_exchange', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Silver Exchange Declaration'),
    'index' => 'entity_id',
    'width' => '170px',
    'filter' => false,
    'sortable'  => false,
    'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Silverexchange',
));
```

Comment: Hi Lokesh Thanks for your answer. Sorry to say this nothing showing in the column for info this see this link  https://ibb.co/cFnoP5

Comment: i think error in `if($coupon_code == 'SE50')` actually  `$coupon_code` values not showing in `Silverexchange.php`.  am using `print_r($coupon_code);` for testing

Comment: Hi Ramesh, I have edited the answer. Change index of 'silver_exchange' to 'entity_id'.

Comment: Hi it's working Bro

Comment: Bro if you free come this chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64544/magento-be